# Regarding Mysql affiliate count

Tags: mysql

So basically I have a quick and dirty affiliate system. I have the columns

```
email
affiliate_id
recruiter_id
```

I want to now create a virtual column to count how many people were recruited based on `affiliate_id`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select recruiter_id, count(*) as recruted
from your_table
group by recruiter_id
```

Comment: this is returning a 1 for all rows in the "recruted column" .

Comment: That is odd. Please edit your question and add example data and expected output.

Comment: Every user has a unique affiliate_id . IF a new user joins using another users affiliate_id, this gets logged as their recruiter_id. I want to count how many users each affiliate has recruited.

Comment: Î edited my answer. Maybe that is what you want. If not, then please update your questions as I mentioned earlier with example data

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Is there way to return all the users and just have 0 if the affiliate has no recruits

Comment: That is possible. But again without exactly knowing what output you want this is just guessing. I recommend asking another question about it and being very specific about your data and the output you expect. Please put a little more effort in your question. So people are motivated to put the same effort in their answers.

Comment: ok thank you for the advice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703972/how-to-count-referalls-mysql