# How to count referalls mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a quick and dirty affiliate system. I have the columns

```
email
affiliate_id
recruiter_id
```

I want to now create a virtual column to count how many people were recruited based on affiliate_id.

So the output I am looking for is

```
email
affiliate_id
total_recruited
```

Sample Data is something like this

```
johndoe1@gmail.com aaaa 
johndoe2@gmail.com bbbb 
johndoe3@gmail.com cccc aaaa
johndoe4@gmail.com dddd aaaa
johndoe5@gmail.com eeee bbbb
```

Query results should look something like this

```
johndoe1@gmail.com aaaa 2
johndoe2@gmail.com bbbb 1
johndoe3@gmail.com cccc 0
johndoe4@gmail.com dddd 0
johndoe5@gmail.com eeee 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

```
SELECT email, affiliate_id, COALESCE(t1.tote_rec, 0) as total_recruited
FROM table t
LEFT JOIN
(   SELECT recruiter_id, COUNT(recruiter_id) as tote_rec
    FROM table
    GROUP BY recruiter_id
) t1 on t1. recruiter_id = t. affiliate_id
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/525f69/1)

you can also do it without a subquery like so

```
SELECT t.email, t.affiliate_id, count(t1.recruiter_id) as total_recruited
FROM test_t t
LEFT JOIN test_t t1 on t1. recruiter_id = t. affiliate_id
GROUP BY t.affiliate_id;
```

another [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/525f69/7)